# Lost Session When Moving From Http to Https

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I am having an issue where moving from http://mysite.com to https://secure.mysite.com causes the user to lose their session information.  What would be the best way to deal with this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `SQL Server` to keep your `Session`.
This will be helpful 
[Configure SQL Server to Store ASP.NET Session State](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

Comment: I believe the issue is that they consider these two urls to be different sites.  So I am not sure this will work seamlessly.

Answer (score 0):

The session is being lost because the url is changing from mysite.com to secure.mysite.com Is it possible to keep the url the same and just use the secure https protocol?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am stuck with these urls.